# Libgdx Pixmap and getFrameBufferPixels

Tags: byte, libgdx, offset, pixmap

I wonder know how to get the **FrameBufferPixel** in a **Pixmap**

I know I must use *getFrameBufferPixels(true)*

But I don't know what parameters to put in

```
new Pixmap(byte[] encodedData, int offset, int len);
```

**Can you show me an exemple who should works ?**

Thanks you

Comment: A Pixmap represents a texture in regular memory, a FrameBuffer represents a render target as a texture.  There are no "FrameBufferPixel" for a Pixmap.  Can you describe what you're trying to do more generally?

Comment: I want to have a Screenshot of the game in a Pixmap

Comment: I want to put a screenshot of my game in a Pixmap for give it a Blur Script wich works only on Pixmap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
new Pixmap(byte[] encodedData, int offset, int len);
```

As far as I know, encodedData needs to hold data from a png, jpg or bmp file, including the file header. The data you receive from getFrameBufferPixels is in RGBA8888 format.
So you can't use this constructor for your screenshot. Instead I would try something like this:

```
byte[] pixelData = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixels(true);
Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), Format.RGBA8888);
ByteBuffer pixels = pixmap.getPixels();
pixels.clear();
pixels.put(pixelData);
pixels.position(0)
```

Comment: ok, but I want that the screenshot be in the Pixmap for give it a blur script, and with your code, the Pixmap you created stay empty... Can you give me a complete code please.

Comment: I also tried this http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Screenshots for put the screenshot into a Pixmap and it doesn't work, it shows a Blue screen with 0.5 alpha... BUT When I save the picture, It works.. BUT I don't want to save the picture.. I just want the pixmap.

Comment: I made a small project. It draws an image once and takes a screenshot afterwards. That screenshot is then converted back to a texture and drawn 3 times to prove it's not empty.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3504939/ScreenshotTest.rar

Comment: Thanks you, you re right, I did a mistake, your code works perfect !

Comment: I guess that ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixels relies only on the FrameBuffer on the screen. How would you do the same for a FrameBuffer object you have created on your own?